# Is it possible to get Browser name and version with KendoUI

Tags: javascript, html, web, kendo-ui

Is it possible to get Browser name and version with KendoUI the same way we
do in other library like jQuery.

Comment: These tools use `navigator.userAgent`. This approach to browser-identification is notoriously unreliable, as jQuery's own documentation states very clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use [WhichBrowser](https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/WhichBrowser) in any javascript you're using, like:

```
Browsers = new WhichBrowser();

// log Browsers to console:
console.log("You are using ", Browsers);

// parse to JSON
JSON.stringify(Browsers);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You can get Kendo UI version from `kendo.version` and you can use jQuery for getting information about the browser using [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)

```
alert ("KendoUI version: " + kendo.version);
alert ("Browser : " + $.browser);
```

but as you can see in jQuery documentation they recommend using a different plug-in for detecting it and if you use Kendo UI version with jQuery 1.9 you will need to use jquery-migrate.